# How to persistant key using KSP in .net?

Tags: .net, security, key

I am making an application using WPF and I would like to use Window's CNG. However, I am having an issue storing an asymmetric key so that it persists throughout different sessions. I would like to make the key so that the public and private key do not change. How do I go about this?

I have been trying to use the KSP to store the key, but have not found out how to properly access and use it. Any key storage method works (so long as it is secure), so I am not tied to the KSP. I have looked around for an answer, but I could not find any that gave a clear explanation.

EDIT: I should mention that although the Microsoft docs for CngKey.Create(name) will create a persisted key, it seems to not work. When I try to use the key again my public and private key values change.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a lot of trial and error, I figured out that it was an issue with my key generation. I will post the code here in case anyone else has a similar question.

The following code sample will create and store a CngKey with the KSP for use with the RSA algorithm:

```
    CngKey key;
    bool keyExists = CngKey.Exists(KEY_NAME);
    if (!keyExists)
    {
        CngKeyCreationParameters parameters = new CngKeyCreationParameters()
        {
            ExportPolicy = CngExportPolicies.AllowPlaintextExport,
            Provider = CngProvider.MicrosoftSoftwareKeyStorageProvider,
            KeyUsage = CngKeyUsages.AllUsages
        };
        CngProperty property = new CngProperty("Length", BitConverter.GetBytes(RSA_KEY_SIZE), CngPropertyOptions.None);
        parameters.Parameters.Add(property);

key = CngKey.Create(CngAlgorithm.Rsa, KEY_NAME, parameters);

}
```